# genfromtxt generates tuples, so does recfromcsv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a csv-file (comma separated) of the following structure:

A1,A2,A3

16516.1556163,163163.48315,41816.844334

When I try to created a 2d matrix out of it using numpy then it is always converted into something like a structured array.
According to the given structure of the csv-file I used:

```
y = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(0,2), names=True)
```

or

```
y = np.recfromcsv('file.csv', usecols=(0,2)
```

In both cases my array will have the shape of (1,) instead of (1,2). Looking at the dtypes generated by genfromtxt or recfromcsv I can tell they are all of the same dtype ('a1', '<f8').

Can you tell me on how to get the array into the right format reading from a csv?

Cheers Thomas

Comment: the shape `(1,)` is correct for this input. The created arrays are recarrays where each field id obtained through `a['col_name']`, where in your case will return arrays with only one element...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109403/numpy-genfromtxt-imports-tuples-instead-of-arrays?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

When I try to reproduce your code, I get:

```
In [71]: c = StringIO("A1,A2,A3\n16516.1556163,163163.48315,41816.844334")

In [72]: x = np.genfromtxt(c,delimiter=',',usecols=(0,2),names=True)
Out[72]: 
array((16516.1556163, 41816.844334), 
      dtype=[('A1', '<f8'), ('A3', '<f8')])

In [73]: x.shape
Out[73]: ()

In [83]: x.item()
Out[83]: (16516.1556163, 41816.844334)

In [129]: x.reshape((1,))
Out[129]: 
array([(16516.1556163, 41816.844334)], 
      dtype=[('A1', '<f8'), ('A3', '<f8')])
```

So `x` is a record array.  With only one data row, it has shape `()` ('scalar').  If you had given it two data rows, the shape would be `(2,)`.  If 'names=False', and you tell it to skip the 1st line, the result (with 2 rows) would be `(2,2)`.

These '...fromtxt' functions, read the file line by line, parsing each line and constructing a list of lists, e.g. `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]`.  This then goes to `np.array` (with the appropriate `dtype`).  And finally it gets a `.squeeze()`, removing all singleton dimensions.

It's this final `squeeze` that turns an array with shape `(1,)` into `()` (or `(1,2)->(2,)`).  You can easily add that dimension back in with a `reshape`.

To create a matrix with 2 columns, you need to skip the header and names:

```
In [121]: x=np.genfromtxt(c,delimiter=',',usecols=(0,2),skip_header=1)

In [122]: x
Out[122]: array([ 16516.1556163,  41816.844334 ])

In [123]: x.shape
Out[123]: (2,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read your `csv` file with `astropy` library that can read tables. Here is a sample implementation:

```
>>> from astropy.io import ascii
>>> from numpy import *
>>> data = ascii.read("test.csv",format='csv',delimiter=',')
>>> print data
      A1           A2           A3     
------------- ------------ ------------
16516.1556163 163163.48315 41816.844334
```

and then use `numpy` to convert it to an array with three columns. Btw, you can not have an array of strings and float numbers.

```
>>> a = hstack((data['A1'],data['A2'],data['A3']))
>>> print a
[  16516.1556163  163163.48315     41816.844334 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was sitting some time over the two suggestions and since I tried basically everything from the first suggestion already I went for astropy. I read in the documentation that csv is supported as a format, but hey, that never worked for me with version 0.3. The supported formats for version 0.3.2 do not include csv and at PyPi that's the latest release.

However, I tried`format='fixed_width'` and something was read in, but the values have been all but misunderstood.

I still don't get it, but when I neglect the the first line with `skip_header=1` and sacrifice the column names completely by not setting `names` (which defaults to `None`) then it works.

Now, when I say:

```
x = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
x.shape
```

results in `(10615, 52)`